# asp.net - JSON formatting in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have SQL table with JSON Content. I have ID and JSON Content in SQL Table. I want the JSON content formatted well in gridview.

SQL table

```
    Id     JSONContent
   --------------------------------------------------
    1     {"ID":"201456", "Address" : "Brooklyn, NY"} 
    2     {"ID":"201457", "Address" : "Queens, NY"}
```

Desired Output (In Grid View)

```
Id   JSONContent
----------------------------------
 1      {
          "ID":"201456",
          "Address" : "Brooklyn, NY"
        }
 2 .    {
          "ID":"201457",
          "Address" : "Queens, NY"
        }
```

Comment: please check https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e79a9f9-90d9-4759-bb54-3c6fa12ddb0e/json-to-gridview?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: How are you binding code to GridView put that in your question.